# How to keep track of established connections using WebSockets

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, websocket, connection

I am trying to get a real-time chat service for cross-platform devices to life. The problem is that 
`System.Net.WebSockets` namespace doesn't allow me directly to keep track of an established connection. I could take a sessionID of the current connection but how can I say perform the following action `await socket.SendAsync(buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, CancellationToken.None)` for a specific client?

If I could use `Microsoft.WebSockets`, I would have the possibility to create a `WebSocketCollection()` and do something like `client.Send(message)`, but I can't send an `ArraySegment<byte[]>` through it. I also think this is more intended for AJAX clients and websites and this stuff.

I now have the following code snippet:

```
public class WSHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    event NewConnectionEventHandler NewConnection;
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(ProcessWSChat);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
    private async Task ProcessWSChat(AspNetWebSocketContext context)
    {
        WebSocket socket = context.WebSocket;
        int myHash = socket.GetHashCode();
        while (true)
        {
        ArraySegment<byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
        WebSocketReceiveResult result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(
            buffer, CancellationToken.None);
            if (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                string userMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                    buffer.Array, 0, result.Count);
                userMessage = "You sent: " + userMessage + " at " +
                    DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " from ip " +
                    context.UserHostAddress.ToString();
                buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(
                    Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userMessage));
                await socket.SendAsync(
                    buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I extend my project, save the sessions/connections and call a specific user connection in order to send it a message?

Comment: What made you choose WebSockets over SignalR?  Just incase, there's a tutorial for [mapping users to connections](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections) with SignalR

Comment: I didn't knew SignalR is supported by Android yet. WebSockets is supported natively by Windows and Xamarin, so I wanted to use this. But as I read now, that would be perfect! Thanks in advice!

Comment: SignalR is just an abstraction over several different types of communication.  Usually it does use WebSockets.  And it's awesome, IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you do not do something like that. The WebSocket should be just and endpoint to another layer or sub-system. For example, an event-driven architecture. On connection, you should start the handler, gather data from the connected socket like the cookie, the URL or whatever, and notify something else that such user with that cookie/url is connected in that socket.

About your code:

- Do not declare the read buffer inside the loop, you can reuse it.
- WebSockets always send text data as UTF8, not ASCII.

This would be a way of keep track of your users in a small project, but I recommend you to plug the WebSocket to another message infrastructure like MassTransit:

```
public class WSHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(ProcessWSChat);
        }
    }

    static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<IPrincipal, WebSocket> _users = new ConcurrentDictionary<IPrincipal, WebSocket>();

    private async Task ProcessWSChat(AspNetWebSocketContext context)
    {
        WebSocket socket = context.WebSocket;
        ArraySegment<byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[4096]);

        //Identify user by cookie or whatever and create a user Object
        var cookie = context.Cookies["mycookie"];
        var url = context.RequestUri;

        IPrincipal myUser = GetUser(cookie, url);

        // Or uses the user that came from the ASP.NET authentication.
        myUser = context.User;

        _users.AddOrUpdate(myUser, socket, (p, w) => socket);

        while (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None)
                                                        .ConfigureAwait(false);
            String userMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Array, 0, result.Count);

            userMessage = "You sent: " + userMessage + " at " +
                DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " from ip " + context.UserHostAddress.ToString();
            var sendbuffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userMessage));

            await socket.SendAsync(sendbuffer , WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None)
                        .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        // when the connection ends, try to remove the user
        WebSocket ows;
        if (_users.TryRemove(myUser, out ows))
        {
            if (ows != socket)
            {
                // whops! user reconnected too fast and you are removing
                // the new connection, put it back
                _users.AddOrUpdate(myUser, ows, (p, w) => ows);
            }
        }
    }

    private IPrincipal GetUser(HttpCookie cookie, Uri url)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this unique code that I couldn't find anywhere! I changed to ASCII Encoding because I thought it would take less resources than encoding with UTF8. I take a closer look at the code because SignalR doesn't work on productive servers and there is no alternative. I'll also take a look at MassTransit!

Comment: Keep in mind that you need Windows 2008/2012 to run websockets, even if you use SignalR. If you do not have those operating systems, you can use a thirdparty framework, like mine: http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/

Comment: I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 setup with .NET Framework 4.5 running. I guess this should work, but - as I said - it SHOULD...but doesn't.

Comment: Please note it is not enabled by default: http://danielhindrikes.se/windows-8/enable-websocket-protocol-in-iis/

Comment: WebSockets support was always working and also works now, just SignalR doesn't work.

Comment: If I try to access the above cookie, I always get a NullReferenceException when I try to compare `context.Cookies["UserName"]` like this `if (cookie != null)`. What's wrong with that? I set it in the client like that: `wsocket.Options.Cookies.Add(new Cookie("UserName", "User1"));`

Comment: the ConcurrentDictionary doesn't seem to save all established connections, just the current user session. How can I store the connections now?

Comment: The dictionary is storing WebSocket objects, that are connections. When the connection dies, the code removes the WebSocket object from the dictionary, because it is unusable. Cookies can only be added during the WebSocket HTTP negotiation, that happens before the creation of the WebSocket object, probably you have to add them before calling `AcceptWebSocketRequest`.

Comment: so, the ConcurrentDictionary is shared between all connected users? It doesn't seem to work like that. If I connect two clients and read all the keypairs, I get one pair, not two. What do I do wrong?

Comment: My bad. The collection should be static. I will give it a try later to be sure.

Comment: I tried it with "readonly static ConcurrentDictionary...", it counts up the connections until I restart debugging. But I can't change the Socket to a specific user...or I do it wrong? I tried `socket = _users[toUser];` but it always logs a WebSocketException "the data format for the current protocol action is invalid" or something like that on the ReceiveAsync-Line.

Comment: Thanks @vtortola!
Everything's fine with your code :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess reinventing the wheel would be very stupid, so I better use SignalR for this purpose.

Thanks @Jonesy for making me aware of this Microsoft library!

**edit:**

SignalR doesn't work properly on non-"IIS Express" mode. "Local IIS" causes the whole project to fail.

**edit:**

SignalR works now. A rewrite rule made it impossible to get the proper path.

Comment: SignalR is very weak in terms of scalability, remember that. They make it clear in their documentation. Check out the "Scaling out" part.

Comment: SignalR is for small projects, or medium projects where you need to broadcast not very segmented information.

Comment: Thank you for that information! I have the goal to create a large messaging service so it should be very large scalable.

Comment: I was cheated in create my end with signalr. Then when it was time to porting my project to Cordova for an android project, connection to the hub is complicated tiresome and maybe diiiiissappoint now I am once again rewritining all the code to use websockets again. be careful with all these signalr lovers. Not enough doccumentatoin in one place for this either.