# Web sockets .net 4.5 how to get a reference to a connection

Tags: asp.net, websocket

I am new to websockets in asp .net, I have started building a simple chat application

I can open a connection using http handler I can send and receive data but my question is: how can I access other client connection  from some handler so that I can send something

I have searched a lot for something similar and I have found this

http://demos.html5support.nl/WebSockets/SimpleChat

I would like to do exactly like in this page but here they are using a non-standard library, I want to do this using standard websocket support in .net 4.5

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you thought about using signalr? http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Comment: I tried it, but in my case I am in need of using websockets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this example : [How to keep track of established connections using WebSockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26263306/how-to-keep-track-of-established-connections-using-websockets/26274839)

Basically you need to keep track of the `WebSocket` objects and associate them with an ID or something in a shared collection. When you want to send something, just retrieve the connection and use it.