# How to send messages from server to a specific client

Tags: c#, websocket

I am using WebSockets and trying to set up a code base for my server-client. I know how to send messages from client to server and I also know how to listen those messages from the server side.

However, how can I send a message back to a client ?

```
// here is the _clientSocket that I accepted
_clientSocket = _serverSocket.Accept();
int received = _clientSocket.Receive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length,
    SocketFlags.None);
// here is the message I got from the client
string receivedMsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_buffer);

if (receivedMsg == "1") 
//TO DO: send back to client "This is a test message from server".
```

Comment: Do you know there's a framework called SignalR? :P

Comment: SignalR can be used without ASP.NET

Comment: WebSockets are well supported already, there is no point in using a polyfill with limited scalability.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to call:

```
_clientsocket.Send(...);
```

Comment: I am using the exact same code to send data from the client to the server, not from the server to client. Also, you don't tell me how to make the client to listen

Comment: Your _clientsocket is the socket on the server to the client. You can call Receive and Send on it ...

Comment: This is how I send data from the **client to the server**. `_clientSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello"));` sends "hello" to the server. The server listens the message like so: `byte[] _dataReceived = new byte[_clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize]; _clientSocket.Receive(_dataReceived);`. You are saying that the same exact code, also can send from the **server to a client** ? I don't understand

Comment: You have a socket on the client, where you can Send and Receive data & a socket (_clientSocket) on the server to Send and Receive data ... imagine it like a garden hose ...

Comment: and you have a second socket on the server to accept connections (_serverSocket)

Comment: Yes, just got the time to test it. Also, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to use the `SendAsync` method:

```
var sendbuffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Whatever text you want to send"));

await socket.SendAsync(sendbuffer , WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Take a look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26274839/307976

Comment: I am using synchronized sockets. Also what is `socket` supposed to be ? Where is the `_clientSocket` and `_serverSocket` from my question ?

Comment: I mean I was expecting something like `_serverSocket.SendTo(_clienSocket, ... , ... , ... );` And then the client to listen like this `_clientSocket.Receive(...);`

Comment: It would be `_clientSocket.SendAsync(...blah...blah` . Also please note that WebSocket standard uses UTF8 enconding and not ASCII.

Comment: Why are you using async ? I am using syncronized sockets as I said. `_clientSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input));` sends data from the client to the server, not from the server to the client. Also, you don't describe how the client listens

Comment: No, if you are accepting that socket in your server side, that client object represents the client, and if you call "Send", it will go to the client.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no sync version: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx